# Paypal Beta Developer account not working

Tags: paypal

after switching to new beta developer paypal, our all sandbox account created or imported email no more in working, 
Can you look please asap

step to getting error:

1. logged with developer account
2. Go in Application->sandbox Account
3. Go to Sandbox Site for any sandbox account
4. logged with sanbox account info
5. getting error:

Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue due to transition from old sandbox to the new site. You need to delete your cookies and re-login to access the sandbox site. Please note that IE has permanent cookies stored on file system that need to be deleted. Firefox or Chrome would work better than IE8.